# How to use <video> to deal the video with an attribute of rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, rotation

I have some video files. The mediainfo:

```
General
Complete name                            : E:\ownCloud\draft\20160720\2016-07-21_01-01-29_41347700.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp41/mp42/isom)
File size                                : 325 KiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 0 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 443 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-07-20 10:44:46
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-07-20 10:44:46

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L1.3
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 6 s 0 ms
Bit rate                                 : 386 kb/s
Width                                    : 240 pixels
Height                                   : 320 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 0.750
Rotation                                 : 90°
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 28.571 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 35.294 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.168
Stream size                              : 283 KiB (87%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-07-20 10:44:46
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-07-20 10:44:46
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 6 s 0 ms
Source duration                          : 6 s 107 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 50.8 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 64.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 37.2 KiB (11%)
Source stream size                       : 37.9 KiB (12%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-07-20 10:44:46
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-07-20 10:44:46
```

You can see the video is recorded with camera rotated.

I try using  like this:

```
<video src="2016-07-21_01-01-21_45791600.mp4" controls>
```

Chrome automatically rotates the video, but Firefox,IE and don't.

I try using css to rotate on IE and Firefox:

```
video
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Internet Explorer 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

It works but the controller is rotated too.
IE:

[image: IE]

The opera now only recognizes `-webkit` but it affects Chrome.

My question is: **How to recognize a video if it has an attribute of rotation?**

And: **How to display the video correctly with rotating and controller?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new problem, the problem has often been with firefox not chrome, several people have complained about it but all to no avail. they finally said it will be fixed on the next browser update. but for the main time. you can use [videojs](http://videojs.com/) to rotate the video without rotating the control, it has several plugin one of which is the rotate plugin.

you can do something like this, just an illustration

```
if ( isfirefox ) {

    <video  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="270" height="360" data-setup='{ "plugins": { "zoomoomrotate": { "rotate": "270", "zoom": "1.4" } } }'>
        <source src="video-source" type="video/mp4">         
  </video>

}
```

you test fotr the browser type, then rotate it.

There is also a recent problem with the new version of chrome ( 52.0.2743). it compressed the video, hence changing the aspect ratio, still looking for a fix for this. this only happens for video recorded on mobile

Comment: No only firefox, but alse IE, Chrome and many browsers based on webkit don't rotate video automaticly.